# Bootstrap 3 tooltip stop working when i set a duration in jquery related toggle

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched for a while but i haven't found an answer, i'm not sure where is the problem  exactly (not sure even if it's a bootstrap error or not), anyway i made a horizzontal navbar fixed in the top of the website, with some elements hidden that i wish to toggle.

those menu entries are a list (as bootstrap says in the docs) and have a class `.hideMe` that is set as hidden with a document.ready function as well as an associated bootstrap's toolbar for each element:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function (){
    $(".hideMe").hide();
    $('.tip').tooltip();  /*.tip is the class of the 'a' anchors that i need as tooltips*/
});
```

if i call the function associated with the toggle onclick everything works fine:

```
function hideMe(){ 
    $(".hideMe").toggle();
}
```

BUT if i set the duration to `slow` the toggle gets animated slowly but i don't see the tooltips anymore like the related function isn't loaded:

```
function hideMe(){ 
    $(".hideMe").toggle('slow'); /*the animation is slow but no tooltip is shown*/
}
```

The same, obviously, occurs even when the speed is `200`, `500` or `fast`. I don't have any clue about this issue and i've tried everything that came to my mind, any idea on how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example to let us see the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything working fine:

See the DEMO here **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/LnvL3/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="hideMe">Click me</div>
<div id="tog"></div>
<div id="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Your Message on tooltip">Hove me</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function (){

    $(".hideMe").click(function(){
        $("#tog").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

External References:

1. JQUERY 1.9.1
2. Bootstrap.min.css
3. Bootstrap tooltip.js [**[link](https://code.google.com/p/phpwcms/source/browse/branches/dev-2.0/include/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js?r=481)**]

Comment: apparently it's something browser-related. After i've tried your code without any success or improvement i've decided to change browser for another test, on chrome (win 8) nothing happens, while on firefox(win 8) everything works fine. On the "bootply" even on chrome works.